# Split data from a text file 8 times to put in CSV in individual rows

Tags: regex, powershell, csv

I need to read some data from a text file and generate the CSV.

I am using this PowerShell script to get the data

```
$PAGE = Get-Content .\DATA.txt | ForEach-Object {
     New-Object PSObject -Property @{
         FIELD1 = [regex]::Matches($_, '^[^\:]*[^\.txt:]').Value
         FIELD2 = [regex]::Match($_, 'DATA').Value
         FIELD3 = [regex]::Match($_, 'DATA\s(.+)').Value
         FIELD4  = [regex]::Match($_, 'DATA\s(\S*)\s(\S*)\s(\S*)\s(\S*)\s(\S*)\s(\S*)\s(\S*)\s(\S*)\s')
     }
}

$PAGE | Select-Object FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4 |
    Export-Csv DATA.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The regex can be tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/Ip9RBW/1). Sample input:

```
file1.txt: DATA 46546 TEST1 EUIRWY 283746827 2 1 3 3
file2.txt: DATA 96873 TEST2 KJH-ASKDJH 928374 0 0 0 0
```

The output of the above script on the given data is coming as this:

```
FIELD1 | FIELD2 | FIELD3                                     | FIELD4
file1  | DATA   | DATA 46546 TEST1 EUIRWY 283746827 2 1 3 3  | FIELD4
file2  | DATA   | DATA 96873 TEST2 KJH-ASKDJH 928374 0 0 0 0 | FIELD4
```

But the intended output is this.

```
FIELD1 | FIELD2 | FIELD3 | FIELD4
file1  | DATA   | D1     | 46546
file1  | DATA   | D2     | TEST1
file1  | DATA   | D3     | EUIRWY
file1  | DATA   | D4     | 283746827
file1  | DATA   | D5     | 2
file1  | DATA   | D6     | 1
file1  | DATA   | D7     | 3
file1  | DATA   | D8     | 3
file2  | DATA   | D1     | 96873
................................
................................
..............and so no 8 times
```

Basically Field4 will always have 8 strings or digits FIELD1 should be the name of the file 8 times FIELD2 will also appear 8 times that too 'DATA' and FIELD3 will always follow this sequence D1....D8. The same is to be repeated for every line in DATA.TXT file. So in sample I have taken 2 lines as file1.txt and file2.txt.

I am unable to think of how should I proceed. As I want to use the similar approach in the script because it's part of my main script and for uniformity I want to use this approach if possible.

Comment: Please provide sample input.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers The test string is already there [link](https://regex101.com/r/Ip9RBW/1)

Comment: Please provide everything that's relevant for your question IN YOUR QUESTION. I'm somewhat less than inclined to go someplace else just to be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the match in a `Where-Object` filter and construct the desired objects in a `for` loop nested inside the `ForEach-Object`:

```
$re = '^(.*?\.txt):\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)$'
$PAGE = Get-Content .\DATA.txt | Where-Object {
    $_ -match $re
} | ForEach-Object {
    for ($i=3; $i -lt $matches.Count; $i++) {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            FIELD1 = $matches[1]
            FIELD2 = $matches[2]
            FIELD3 = "D$($i-2))"
            FIELD4 = $matches[$i]
        }
    }
}
```